# What CSS3 properties does the "col" element support?

Tags: html, css

With regards to the "col" element in HTML (the element used to style multiple columns in a table), I would like to know the **CSS3** properties that it supports. I have not been able to find a comprehensive list anywhere on the Internet. There have been suggestions that there are not many properties that are supported, so what are they?

Properties supported prior to CSS3 include:

- background-attachment
- background-blend-mode
- background-color
- background-image
- background-position
- background-repeat
- visibility (using 'collapse' property)
- width

Comment: May I ask you ... What is the reason for this question? Do you have some specific problem or an issue with applying some CSS?

Comment: Please read it first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

Comment: @GibboK No particular reason, other than trying to use something that you would think helps to make it easier to develop tables with on webpages. FYI, I was originally trying to apply the 'break-all' value of the 'word-break' property of a single column, rather than repeating it multiple times for each cell in the column.

Comment: @Rahul I did read the MDN page that you referred me to, prior to posting this question. It makes no mention of CSS properties that can be used, only HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are CSS3 properties that I have confirmed works with col elements:

- background-clip
- background-origin
- background-size

I will add to this list as further information comes to hand.

Answer (score 5):

Applicable properties are [listed in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns):

The following properties apply to column and column-group elements:

> '**border**' The various border properties apply to columns only if
> 'border-collapse' is set to 'collapse' on the table element. In that
> case, borders set on columns and column groups are input to the
> conflict resolution algorithm that selects the border styles at every
> cell edge.
>
> '**background**' The background properties set the background
> for cells in the column, but only if both the cell and row have
> transparent backgrounds. See "Table layers and transparency."
>
> '**width**'
> The 'width' property gives the minimum width for the column.
>
> '**visibility**' If the 'visibility' of a column is set to 'collapse',
> none of the cells in the column are rendered, and cells that span into
> other columns are clipped. In addition, the width of the table is
> diminished by the width the column would have taken up. See "Dynamic
> effects" below. Other values for 'visibility' have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS** properties and **pseudo-classes** that may be specially useful to style the `<col>` element:

1. the `width` property to control the width of the column;
2. the `:nth-child` **pseudo-class** to set the alignment on the cells of the column;
3. the `text-align` property to align all cells content
   on the same character, like `'.'`.

**In CSS3 style like this**

```
table > tr > td:nth-child(3)
```

**In CSS2 style like this**

```
table > tr > td:first-child + td + td
```